# Casting to Enum

Tags: enums, casting

I have the following code.

```
private Enum MyEnum
{
    VALUE1=5, VALUE2=4, VALUE3=3, VALUE4=2, VALUE5=1
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["EnumValue"] = "VALUE1";
    MyEnum test = (MyEnum) Session["EnumValue"];
}
```

In the page load, after the casting i have the value of the variable 'test' = 'VALUE2'.

I am expecting it to get test ='VALUE1'. Is there anything wrong with the code

Answer (score 6):

You can't simply cast the string value back into the Enum, you have to parse it:

```
MyEnum enumValue = (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), (string)Session["EnumValue"]);
```

Comment: ok. The code is not showing any error. Is it the normal behaviour?

Comment: Normally you would do something like Joop's answer, using the value of the enum and not the string.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you working with a string an not with the enum? Like:

```
private Enum MyEnum
{
     VALUE1=5, VALUE2=4, VALUE3=3, VALUE4=2, VALUE5=1
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["EnumValue"] = MyEnum.VALUE1;
    MyEnum test = (MyEnum) Session["EnumValue"];
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's code from 2001 back when ASP Classic 3.0 didn't support anything but strings in session :-)  #historylesson

Comment: Good comment on an answer of nearly two years ago ;)

Comment: I guess that makes it meta-history? ASP Classic was my introduction to commercial coding so it's burned into my memory.